# requestLocationUpdates. Помогите разобраться

Tags: android, gps, location, android-location

Стоит задача. При нажатии на кнопку, запускается служба requestLocationUpdates. Работать она должна 5 секунд и по истечению времени должна прекращать работу. Если один из провайдеров(GPS или NETWORK) успел за это время определить координаты телефона, то записать их в textView, если нет, то вывести соответствующее сообщение о том, что координаты не определены. Инфа о координатах должна показываться пользователю только после завершения работы requestLocationUpdates. Помогите, пожалуйста с реализацией этого. Или хотя бы подскажите, куда копать.

```
 private void startLocationUpdates() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mFusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest
                    .setInterval(0)
                    .setFastestInterval(0)
                    .setMaxWaitTime(0)
                    .setNumUpdates(1)
                    .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY), mLocationCallback, null);
        }
}
```

Это метод для запуска службы. Это моё первое приложение на android, да и с джавой знакомиться начал совсем недавно. Прошу помочь.

Comment: private void getLastLocation() {
        if(this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission_group.LOCATION)== PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED)
            return;
        if(locationManager==null)
        {
            return;
        }
        for (String provider : locationManager.getAllProviders()) {
            onLocationChanged(locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider));
        }
    }

Comment: пробуй запросить последние координаты, они возвращаются сразу,  а не через время как с реквестом.

Comment: т.е. мне запросить последние координаты уже после того, как отработала служба реквест?

Comment: нет, он тебе вернет координаты сразу при запросе. но они будут последними полученными, а не текущими, но если сеть включена постоянно, то весьма вероятно что они будут близки к текущему местоположению.